# How to add birthdate in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, date

I'm using `moderncv` and I'm having an issue adding birthdate

This is the code I'm using

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle[right]{classic}
\moderncvcolor{burgundy}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.8cm}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{24}{0}\bfseries\upshape}
\firstname{\vspace{2mm}John\vspace{2mm}}
\lastname{Doe}
\dateofbirth{1987-02-13}
\address{24 Groove Street, LA, USA}
\phone[mobile]{+123456789}
\email{john.doe@gmail.com}
\photo[50pt][1pt]{photo}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

The date is displayed on top of the image, as `\dateofbirth` is not recognized by `moderncv`.

[image]

I want to put the birthdate excactly before the address but I don't know how.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [Moderncv adding date of birth to personal information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267604/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last it depends on which version of `moderncv` you use.  My example is for the current one, version 2.0.0.

The following code adds an command `\dateofbirth` and patches the code of the class:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dateofbirth}[1]{\def\@dateofbirth{#1}}
\patchcmd{\makecvhead} % <cmd>
  {\if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi} % <search>
  {\if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
   \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@dateofbirth}}{}{\makenewline Date of birth \@dateofbirth}%
  } % <replace>
  {}{} % <success><failure>
\makeatother
\dateofbirth{1987-02-13}
```

So with the following MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle[right]{classic}
\moderncvcolor{burgundy}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.8cm}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{24}{0}\bfseries\upshape}
\firstname{\vspace{2mm}John\vspace{2mm}}
\lastname{Doe}

\address{24 Groove Street, LA, USA}
\phone[mobile]{+123456789}
\email{john.doe@gmail.com}
\photo[50pt][1pt]{photo}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dateofbirth}[1]{\def\@dateofbirth{#1}}
\patchcmd{\makecvhead} % <cmd>
  {\if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi} % <search>
  {\if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
   \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@dateofbirth}}{}{\makenewline Date of birth \@dateofbirth}%
  } % <replace>
  {}{} % <success><failure>
\makeatother
\dateofbirth{1987-02-13}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

After changeing the line

```
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@dateofbirth}}{}{\makenewline Date of birth \@dateofbirth}%
```

in the patch to

```
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@dateofbirth}}{}{\makenewline Date of birth \textbf{\@dateofbirth}}%
```

I get the following result:

[image]

As you can see above the red line the date is printed in bold ...

Comment: Thanks it's working now. But what If I want to give bold effect to the birthdate ? Using textbf doesn't work

Comment: I changed it but it's not working

Comment: no the font shows bold in other parts of the document but not on the personal info like birthdate, address, phone, email...

Comment: I'm using overleaf and no errors or warnings are being shown. I changed the line and added textbf to dateofbirth but it won't work

Comment: I just solved it by adding \color{rgb(0,0,0)} before dateofbirth. Thank you for your help.